# Centering and renaming the title of bibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

In the following I have centered the title of bibliography page. The problem is that in the second and the third page of the bibliography the title are also centered. I would like that the title page at the second and the third page, remain unaffected.

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{title of book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand\bibname{\centerline{my-references}}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{my-references}




\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}
\bibitem{1}


\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit dirty to put a `\centerline` inside `\bibname`. So here is an even dirtier way to compensate for the problem that it causes:

```
\renewcommand\bibname{\centerline{my-references}\global\def\bibname{my-references}}
```